# read "/" without being changed to "\/" in php

Tags: php, image, base64, hosting, encode

I've been trying to read encode image from php and my php code is

```
<?php

$configs = include('config.php');

$dbhost = $configs['host'];
$dbuser = $configs['user'];
$dbpass = $configs['pass'];
$dbname = $configs['dbname'];
$tblbarang = 'tbl_barang';

$response = array();
$response["result"] = array();

try
{
    mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);


    {
        if(isset($_GET["id_penjual"]))
        {
            $id_penjual=$_GET["id_penjual"];

            $querysel = "SELECT b.id_barang, b.nama_barang, b.harga, b.stok, b.deskripsi_barang, b.id_kategori, b.id_penjual, b.id_image, i.nama, i.image FROM tbl_barang b join tbl_image i on b.id_image=i.id_image WHERE id_penjual =$id_penjual";
            $query = '';
            $querysel.=$query;
            $result = mysql_query($querysel);
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $temp = array();
                $temp["id_barang"] = $row["id_barang"];
                $temp["nama_barang"] = $row["nama_barang"];
                $temp["harga"] = $row["harga"];
                $temp["stok"] = $row["stok"];
                $temp["deskripsi_barang"] = $row["deskripsi_barang"];
                $temp["id_kategori"] = $row["id_kategori"];
                $temp["id_penjual"] = $row["id_penjual"];
                $temp["id_image"] = $row["id_image"];
                $temp["nama"] = $row["nama"];
                $temp["image"] = $row["image"];

                array_push($response["result"],$temp);

            }
                $response["message"]=0;
        }
        else
            $response["message"]=1;
    }
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    $response["message"]=0;
}

$response = json_encode($response);
echo $response;
```

but when i insert the encode code of the image to database the result is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSckI.jpg

and i can't read the image because when the encode image have a "\" it will turn to "/" when i access the database from web service

please help me, thank you

Comment: You are storing it as json so are you decoding it when you are trying to use it?

Comment: Some characters need to be "escaped" inside a json encoded string, so that they lose their "special meaning". That is perfectly normal, it protects that character from "breaking things". The escape character will be removed again when decoding the json string again.

Comment: Do you know stripcslashes http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stripcslashes.php ?

Comment: Are you struggling with local and remote file paths? e.g. localhost (c:\home\) webserver (/home/images)

Comment: @chriz I'm using a remote file paths

Comment: Have you tried without `json_encode` or have you tried decoding it and seeing if that solves the issue?